# How to solve the problema "No logs created yet" EMR?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to create a Step in a cluster using a jar location in S3 (AWS), but it Failed returning: "no logs created yet". I tried to use IAM User and Root, the error is the always same. In the log appear the information "warn step failed with exitcode 1". A possible solution that I've find here it's to use Databricks, but I don't know if the results will be the same and I don't know Databricks.

jar location: command-runner.jar
arguments: `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster s3://datalake-jaque-igti-edc/emr-code/pyspark/job_spark.py`